# Indicate upvotes on CW questions/answers as such

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, community-wiki, up-votes, reputation-history

It appears that now upvotes on CW posts appear on the reputation tab of the profile page:

[image]

It would be nice to have some sort of indicator that these are upvotes on CW posts - when I first saw them I didn't understand why I have upvotes with no reputation attached, first thing in the day...

Some sort of indicator would make these more visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree.  Perhaps something like this?

[image: mock-up of wiki upvote - 1]

(Note, it would have the standard red if it is a downvote)

Or this?

[image: mock-up of wiki upvote - 2]

(Again, with the standard red if it is a downvote)

Personally, I'm partial to the first (since we're used to lower-case lettering for indicators such as this, but I can go either way.

The point is, that empty space can be used for something to make the experience better for those lines.

Comment: Visually, I like either one. Clear and to the point. I favour `CW` as it is a common acronym in the network and the `wiki` notation by itself may be more confusing.

Comment: And maybe also something similar when the reputation cap has been reached? That's a bit difficult if one gets partial rep (like 4 points out of 10) for some upvote.

Comment: Disagree with Oded. Not only are the lower-case letters of `wiki` much more aesthetically pleasing, but I don't think most people know what the `CW` acronym means. Heck, I'd have to spend a while scratching my head if I saw that. Everyone knows what a wiki is. CW looks like [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_CW_Television_Network).